# Error trying to run rbenv install 2.5.1

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl-certificate, rbenv

I'm trying to install ruby using rubenv but i'm running into following error:

```
rbenv install 2.5.1 -v
/tmp/ruby-build.20180525142355.3872 ~
Downloading ruby-2.5.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.5/ruby-2.5.1.tar.bz2
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
error: failed to download ruby-2.5.1.tar.bz2

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 18.04 using ruby-build 20180424)
```

I'm using Windows 10 Subsytem for Linux.  Issue seems to be related to certs but i don't know how to go around it.

Comment: Try doing `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates && sudo update-ca-certificates`. If `ca-certificates` is already installed, try updating it with `apt-get`.

Comment: @vcsjones tried sudo apt-get install ca-certificates and it said:  ca-certficates is already the newest version.  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.